# My embedded resource has mysteriously vanished from the assembly, vb.net vs2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an application that has a .sql file in it. The sql file is set to Embedded Resource. When I run the following code, I get an empty string array indicating there are no embedded resources.

However this project has been working fine previously.

Any ideas?

```
Dim p As String() = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures. I tried various things, then rebuilt / built my solution after each one, but it wasn't until I specifically selected Clean Solution that the problem was fixed.

I guess this is a quirk of our 2010 release which still hasn't been updated to RC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim names as String() = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(<any type name of current assembly>)).GetManifestResourceNames()
```